ServiceStack.OrmLite generated query loses type information set on subquery parameter
Recently I found an article describing how to include a table-valued parameter (TVP) in an arbitrary ServiceStack.OrmLite query.  This method works great when the TVP is included on a single query.  However, when attempting to use this method with a subquery, the TVP's SqlDbType and TypeName properties are lost when the subquery TVP is merged into the main query.
The method described in the article uses a custom OrmLiteConverter to convert a DataTable to a user-defined table type in SQL Server.
CREATE TYPE [dbo].[Integer_Table_Type] AS TABLE(
    [Id] [int] NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF)
)
GO

public class SqlServerDataTableConverter : OrmLiteConverter
{
    public override string ColumnDefinition
        => throw new NotImplementedException("Only used to pass a list of Ids as a parameter.");

    public override void InitDbParam(IDbDataParameter p, Type fieldType)
    {
        if (p is SqlParameter)
        {
            var sqlParameter = p as SqlParameter;
            sqlParameter.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Structured;
            sqlParameter.TypeName = "dbo.Integer_Table_Type";
        }
    }
}

Note the name of the SQL type matches the TypeName property on the SqlParameter. The converter is then registered with the OrmLiteConfig.DialectProvider.
OrmLiteConfig.DialectProvider.RegisterConverter<DataTable>(new SqlServerDataTableConverter());

In order to make this converter easy to use, we create a new extension method on SqlExpression<T>.
public static SqlExpression<T> JoinToList<T>(this SqlExpression<T> self, Expression<Func<T, int>> expression, DataTable table)
{
    var sourceDefinition = ModelDefinition<T>.Definition;

    var property = self.Visit(expression);
    var parameter = self.ConvertToParam(table);

    // Expected SQL: INNER JOIN @0 ON "Parent"."EvaluatedExpression"= "@0".Id
    var onExpression = $@"ON ({self.SqlTable(sourceDefinition)}.{self.SqlColumn(property.ToString())} = ""{parameter}"".""Id"")";
    var customSql = $"INNER JOIN {parameter} {onExpression}";
    self.CustomJoin(customSql);

    return self;
}

With those puzzle pieces, I now wish to construct a query as follows:
public class Owner
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}

public class Pet
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int OwnerId { get; set; }

    public int Type { get; set; }
}

public enum PetType
{
    Dog = 1,
    Cat = 2
}

public class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        OrmLiteConfig.DialectProvider = SqlServer2019Dialect.Provider;
        OrmLiteConfig.DialectProvider.RegisterConverter<DataTable>(new SqlServerDataTableConverter());

        var table = new DataTable();
        table.Columns.Add("Id", typeof(int));
        Enumerable.Range(1, 5).Select(x => table.Rows.Add(x));

        int petType = (int)PetType.Dog;

        var subQuery = OrmLiteConfig.DialectProvider.SqlExpression<Owner>()
            .JoinToList(x => x.Id, table);

        var query = OrmLiteConfig.DialectProvider.SqlExpression<Pet>()
            .Where(x => x.Type == petType)
            .And(x => Sql.In(x.Id, subQuery));
    }
}

When inspecting the Params property of subQuery, we see a single SqlParameter with the specified SqlDbType of SqlDbType.Structured as well as the specified TypeName of dbo.Integer_Table_Type.
When we inspect the Params property of query, we see two parameters.  One for the petType and one for the parameter that was merged from subQuery.  However, the latter now has a SqlDbType of SqlDbType.Variant and a TypeName of string.Empty.  Since the type of the parameter is now incorrect, the query fails with this error message:
The incoming tabular data stream (TDS) remote procedure call (RPC) protocol stream is incorrect.

Is there a way to prevent the subquery parameter's SqlDbType and TypeName from being lost when the subquery is merged into the main query?
I put a minimal reproduction of this issue up on GitHub here.
